# Need to select one row in table by Spring Data JPA in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

my table is StudetDetails (contain ID,STUDENT_NAME,DES) I need to get all the value of studentName using SpringDataJpa.

My entity is:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="Student_Details")
public class StudentDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME")
private String studentName;
}
```

My repository is:

```
    public interface StudentDetailsRepository  extends JpaRepository<StudentDetails, Long>{

    public List<StudentDetails> findAllByStudentName(); 
                                ---------------------
}
```

findAllByStudentName() Is this one correct way???

service class is::::

```
    @Autowired
StudentDetailsRepository stuDetailsRepository;

List<AddInsuranceDTO> getStudentDetils(){

vendorDetails = stuDetailsRepository.findAllByStudentName();
}
```

I am getting error:`Error creating bean with name 'StudentDetailsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException`

kindly help please!!!

Comment: Have you created an implementation for your StudentDetailsRepository interface

Comment: yes,, in service i have done that